# Terminal Profiles not being loaded

Tags: terminal, kali-linux, gnome, gnome-terminal, theme

Eve though in dconf the profiles i installed are shown

```
> dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/

:3fab5042-3b59-44c2-b86e-df287109b3d7/
:93be6823-4719-4dea-be06-ebf0ae9091d8/
:Aci/
:Wild-cherry/
:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/
default
list
```

In my terminal preferences they are not shown so that i can change the profile
[image]

How can i resolve this issue, also i must say that i changed the curent value of profile in the dconf editor as another profile but still nothing in effect.

[image]

Also i must say that after i manually add profiles with the '+' button in the terminal preferences, if i add a new profile with "gogh" all the profiles i created manually are deleted, just the default profile left.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i found a solution. The problem was with the wrong uuid format like @egmont said. The solution was to export the profiles with dconf dump from another working machine and get the right uuid, than importing those profiles with dconf load. After that i just added those uuids in the /profiles:/list. Ant there was the profiles in the preferences. Thanks for all the replies

Answer (score 0):

The list of available profiles is stored in `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/list`, and updated whenever you create or remove a profile using GNOME Terminal's Preferences panel.

(Don't ask me why it's stored under a separate key, rather than querying the list of subfolders. It might boil down to technical limitations of dconf or other possible backends behind gsettings, or legacy reasons, I'm not sure.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes i have all my profiles in `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/list` but they are not in the preferences of the gnome-terminal so that i can change it. Profiles in that path doesn't show up in the preferences of terminal, this is my issue.

Comment: Just double checking that you're indeed also talking about an entry called `list`, rather than the listing? Does the output of `dconf read /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/list` list them all? If so then it's interesting... what if you create a new profile from the terminal's preferences dialog? Does it appear there? Maybe the entire tree where the settings are taken from is different for you, you could do a recursive `dconf dump /` to locate where the newly created profile is stored, that could help?

Comment: Yes it does list all of  profiles here is the output `['b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9', '14a15cca-d3d1-45b5-9191-7434f9169437', 'Aci']`

Comment: This really doesn't match the llisting in your original post. Also I'm wondering if IDs that don't match the UUID format are perhaps ignored, I don't know.

Comment: That is because i resetted my profiles and than tried again. But still as you can see the list property shows that i have 3 profiles one of them being Aci which i get with gogh, but none of them listed in the terminal preferences. And what is the needed format for profile uuid's maybe i can edit them. I edited and added some new information on the original post by the way.

Comment: I see you added a section about the tool `gogh` that you use and which wipes out your earlier profiles. I have no idea what this tool does, but apparently does it wrong. Create a dump of your entire dconf database using `dconf dump /` both before running `gogh` (with many gnome-terminal profiles) and after it, and compare them to catch the differences. That might help you locate and fix the problem. Also, may I kindly suggest to seek help at / complain at / file bug report against `gogh` as that seems to be the problem, whatever it does, not gnome-terminal. I'm afraid I can't help any further.

Comment: I think this is because gogh as you said, when i installed a theme with gogh it's uuid in the dconf is wrong, as you can see in the original post's pictures some profiles has names like 'Aci" instead of uuid's. This my be the reason as you said. Do you know how can i change that uuid in the dconf editor. Thanks you for your help up to now.

Comment: dconf doesn't seem to have an option to rename a key. Probably the easiest is to fix the gogh script, replace Aci with a hardwired random uuid, or the output of `uuidgen`. I strongly recommend to you to reach out to gogh's developers for further help in getting to know why it doesn't work for you, and whether it works for them.